# Python: abort and retry a sync function after some time

Tags: python

I'm developing a standard python script file (no servers, no async, no multiprocessing, ...) i.e. a classic data science program where I load data, process it as dataframes, and so on. Everything is synchronous.

At some point, I need to call a function of an external library which is totally external to me (I have no control on it, I don't know how it does what it does), like

```
def inside_my_function(...):
  # My code
  result = the_function(params)
  # Other code
```

Now, this `the_function` sometimes never terminates (I don't know why, probably there are bugs or some conditions which makes it stuck, but it's completely random), and when it happens my program gets stuck as well.

Since I **have** to use it and it cannot be modified, I would like to know if there is a way for example to wrap it in another function which calls `the_function`, waits for some timeout, and if `the_function` returns before the timeout the result is returned, otherwise `the_function` is somehow killed, aborted, skipped, whatever, and retried up to n times.

I realise that in order to *execute `the_function`* and *check for timeout* at the same time for example multithreading will be needed, but I'm not sure if it makes sense and how to implement it correctly without doing bad practices.

How would you proceed?

EDIT: I would avoid multiprocessing because of the great overhead and because I don't want to overcomplicate things with serializability and so on.

Thank you

Comment: It's a tricky question if you want to use multithreading only, as there's no official way (as far as I know) to kill a thread stuck in an infinite loop. You could execute your function in [another process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process) and use [terminate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) to kill the process after a certain amount of time if it doesn't return. To retrieve the process result, you could store the result on a file, and check it every few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time 
import random
import threading


def func_that_waits():
    t1 = time.time()
    while (time.time() - t1) <= 3:
        time.sleep(1)
        if check_unreliable_func.worked:
            break
    if not check_unreliable_func.worked:        
        print("unreliable function has been working for too long, it's killed.")

def check_unreliable_func(func):
    check_unreliable_func.worked = False
    def inner(*args,**qwargs):
        func(*args,**qwargs)
        check_unreliable_func.worked = True
    return inner
        
def unreliable_func():   
    working_time = random.randint(1,6)
    time.sleep(working_time)
    print(f"unreliable_func has been working for {working_time} seconds")
 

to_wait = threading.Thread(target=func_that_waits)
main_func = threading.Thread(target=check_unreliable_func(unreliable_func), daemon=True)

main_func.start()
to_wait.start()
```

`Unreliable_func` - the function we do not know if it works
`check_unreliable_func(func)` - decorator the only purpose of which is to make `to_wait` thread know that `unreliable_func` returned something and so there is no sense for `to_wait` to work further
the main thing to understand is that `main_func` thread is daemon one so it means that when `to_wait` thread is terminated all daemon threads are terminated automatically and no matter what they've been doing in the moment

Of course it's really far from being best practice, I just show how it can be done. And how it should be done - I myself would be glad to see it too.